# Check real part of a complex number with logarithmic summand.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Consider $t\ge 0$, $u=(u_1,u_2)^\top\in i\mathbb{R}^2$, $x=(x_1,x_2)^\top\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $x_1\ge x_2^2$ and following complex number

$$z:=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-2u_1t)+\frac{t\ (u_2)^2  + 2 u^\top x}{2(1-2u_1t)}$$
I want to determine the real part of $z$, but I am struggling to rewrite $z$ into a usual complex number $z=a+ib$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular: How can I rewrite the logarithmic summand as complex number?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try $\text{Re}(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $u_1=i\,v_1$ and $u_2=i\,v_2$ with real $v_1,v_2$. Then $2\mbox{Re }x=x+\bar x$ and $\mbox{Re }(\ln(x))=\frac12\ln(x\bar x)$ for all $x$, whatever the branch of $\ln$, imply after a short calculation that
$$4\mbox{Re }z=-\ln(1+4v_1^2t^2)-\frac{2t}{1+4v_1^2t^2}(v_2^2+4v_1v^Tx).$$
Here $v_2^2+4v_1v^Tx=v_2^2+4v_1v_2x_2+4v_1^2x_1=(v_2+2v_1x_2)^2+4v_1^2(x_1-x_2^2)\geq0$ because of the hypothesis $x_1\geq x_2^2$. Now it becomes clear that $\mbox{Re }z\leq0$.

Comment: Using $\overline{\ln(z)}=\ln(\overline{z})$, I get the same result. Thank you!

Comment: @USER408858 Actually, here it is better to use that $\mbox{Re }(\ln (z))=\ln(|z|)$ and avoid all issues with multivaluedness...